# Webkit gradient background-gradient in html5 progress bar?

Tags: css, html

In an attempt to color the inside of the progress bar I use the below code:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {
  background-color:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom ,left top,from(#C6E6E6),to(#D1E4E6)) ;
}
```

However the gradients do not work,
Only simple colors.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
progress::-webkit-progress-bar-value {
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom ,left top,from(#C6E6E6),to(#D1E4E6)) ;
}
```

`background` instead of `background-color` and `webkit` instead of `weblit`.